# Laravel Nova поле Trix кнопка подчеркивания

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте подскажите мб кто делал, кто знает как добавить кнопку подчеркивания у редактора Trix.

в файле app/Nova/ServiceElement.php
есть описание полей в protected $view_type стоит

```
'description'=>[
                'title'=>'Описание',
                'rules'=>['required', 'max:1500'],
                'type'=>'Laravel\Nova\Fields\Trix'
],
```

штатно нету такой возможности почему то, либо версия мб не та